# How to find length of a string

Tags: c++, string, string-length

how can i find a length of a string using data type " char "  i tried it many time but i did not work . i also see cplusplus tutorial but could not fix example under below

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    char str1[80];
    char str2[80];

    cout << "Enter string 1 : ";
    cin.getline(str1,80); cout << endl;
    cout << "Enter string 2 : ";
    cin.getline(str2,80);cout << endl;
    cout << "String 1  is :-> " << (unsigned)strlen(str1) << endl;
    cout << "String 1  is :-> " << (unsigned)strlen(str2) << endl;
}
```

Comment: Should work pretty fine, what is you problem?

Comment: use strlen ( http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strlen/ )

Comment: Wrong header, change `#include <string>` to `#include <cstring>`. The other one is for the `std::string` class, not the c-string functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using C++ I would strongly suggest move away from `char*` for strings and start using `std::string`.

```
string str1;
string str2;

cout << "Enter string 1 : ";
cin >> str1; cout << endl;
cout << "Enter string 2 : ";
cin >> str2; cout << endl;
cout << "String 1  is :-> " << str1.size() << endl;
cout << "String 2  is :-> " << str2.size() << endl;
```

PS: Your posted code works for me.